# Select2 is Not Working In bootstrap 4 and laravel

Tags: php, laravel

[Select2](https://select2.org/) is not working. I don't see any effect. I need to apply "Multi-select boxes (pillbox)" style From Select2.

I am using bootstrap 4. I think this is the problem.

What I have tried so far is showed below,

**PHP**

```
<div class="form-group" >        
  <label for="exampleFormControlInput">Tags</label>
  <select multiple class="form-control tags">  >  <!-- Multiple To Select more than one but need press ctrl+select -->

              @foreach ($tags as $tagname)

              <option>{{$tagname->tag}}</option>

           @endforeach

  </select>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

${(function() {
    $('.tags').select2();
});

</script>
```

Comment: how are you ordering your javascript files? are you getting any error in your browser console?

Comment: first of all you have include js and css file to load the select2 for multiple select value in your option box.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have imported the css and the javascript file

This is my view, I used select2 in my vendor.

```
<label>Vendor <span style="color: red">*</span></label>
<select class="form-control" name="vendor_id" required="required" id="vendor">
    <option value="">Select Vendor</option>
    @if($vendors)
        @foreach($vendors as $key => $value)
            <option value="{{ $value->id }}">{{ $value->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</select>
```

As you can see I declared an id because I will use it in my select2. See my code below how I implement the select2 in my vendor.

```
$('#vendor').select2({
        placeholder: "Select Vendor" // you can change this
    });
```

And if you want some event with that select2 here my code.

```
$(document).on('select2:select', '#vendor', function(e){
                var id = $(this).val();
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                })
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/purchases/purchase-orders/getVendorTerms',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {id:id},
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response != '') {
                            $('#terms').val(response.term);
                        }else{
                            $('#terms').val('');
                        }
                        editGetGoodThru();
                    }
                });
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Select2 depends on the order of js included, try including them in order below.
Like jQuery ->jQuery UI -> Bootstrap  -> Select2.

Comment: This can be a comment and not an answer. Please, read the rules of this community.